# How to use an JSON return from a php query into an foreach loop?

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, foreach

i am using Codeigniter and inside a function i call a controller to return data which I want to use in an foreach to built an insert statement.

The JSON returned looks like this:

```
{
    "Data": [
        {
            "id": "743",
            "day": "1",
            "day_type": "Party",
            "day_dresscode": "Black",
            "day_p_id": "1",
            "description": "Test desc",
            "name": "test"
        },
        {
            "id": "743",
            "day": "2",
            "day_type": "Party",
            "day_dresscode": "White",
            "day_p_id": "1",
            "description": "Test desc 1",
            "name": "test 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

my php looks like below:

```
// This where i got my JSON
$datavar = $this->model->get_json_data($id,$code); 

// This is to decode the JSON
$datavar_decode['Data'] = json_decode($datavar,true);
```

Below is my foreach:

```
$i = 1;

       foreach($datavar_decode['Data'] as $data):

           $data_insert = array(
               'val1'    => $data['val1'],
               'val2'    => $data['val2'],
               'val3'    => $data['val3'],
               'val4'    => $data['val4']
           );


        $this->db->insert('mssqltable', $data_insert);

       $i++;
       endforeach;
```

It gives me below error:

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Comment: Why the json? Why not just get the result or row from the DB class and be on your way?

Comment: I would. But it is telling me that `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

Comment: So instead of using `$query->result()` you just use `$query->result_array()`, or if you're just fetching a row use `$query->row_array()`

Comment: Nice, didn't  came across `result_array()` yet, but it works. If you wanna post this as answer, i would accept.

Comment: OK, I just made it an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use json.

You're problem is that you are returning an array of objects, and that's the behavior you get from `$query->result()` or if you use `$query->row()` then you get an object representing a single row.

In order to return an array, use `$query->row_array()` for a single row, or for multiple records returned you would use `$query->result_array()`.

See all the details: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code to test that your `$datavar_decode['Data']`  doesn't allocate an empty array when you've got nothing to begin with anyway.

```
if (is_array($datavar_decode['Data']) || is_object($datavar_decode['Data']))
{
    foreach ($datavar_decode['Data'] as $data)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: nah,.. i know it isn"t empty. The JSON is a steady value on DB.